# Apply a style to a select box, why doesn't it work?

Tags: html, css

I want to put a style to a select box, I tried in the following codes but the problem is that with less and rise letters in the tag option, it doesn't change width style select box and it is fixed. How can it be done with 'width="auto"'?.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uG3gq/

```
<div class="select_box" style="margin: 10px 5px 0 5px;">
    <select name="type_star">
        <option disabled="disabled" value="">Select</option>
        <option>Ttttttttttttttttttttt</option>
        <option>Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>
</div>

.select_box {
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(http://img4up.com/up2/17845058228414984898.png) no-repeat right #9ff;
    height:24px;
    font:13px Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color:#888888;
    padding:0;
}
.select_box select {
    background:transparent;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border:1px soild #666;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#888888;
    height:26px;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either leave it without setting an explicit width and let the browser to handle the width automatically. In this case the browser will determine the longest option and set the width of the select element according to that. Or you could set it with a width like `width=200px;` which will give an explicit width.

Unless you want write some Javascript to determine the longest option and set the width dynamically, I don't think this is possible (AFAIK)

Comment: How can fix these in my code?(Please give me example in my code)

Comment: have a look at here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198670/jquery-select-box-and-loop-help